# Issues with my iam role when using AWS lambda to trigger an async amazon Comprehend job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-comprehend

I am currently using AWS lambda to trigger an asynch Amazon Comprehend job. The data I am using is stored in an input folder in a S3 bucket, and I am trying to output the file in that same bucket, in an output folder. The roles I have for this job are "ComprehendFullAccess" and "AWSLambdaExecute", and this is the following code.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket = "bucketName"
    key = "input/inputTextFile.txt"
    text = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    review = str(text['Body'].read())
    client = boto3.client('comprehend')
    response = client.start_sentiment_detection_job(
        InputDataConfig={
            'S3Uri': 's3://bucketName/input/inputTextFile.txt',
            'InputFormat': 'ONE_DOC_PER_LINE',
            'DocumentReaderConfig': {
                'DocumentReadAction': 'TEXTRACT_ANALYZE_DOCUMENT',
                'DocumentReadMode': 'SERVICE_DEFAULT',
                'FeatureTypes': [
                    'FORMS'
                ]
            }
        },
        OutputDataConfig={
            'S3Uri': 's3://bucketName/output/'
        },
        DataAccessRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::randomNumbers:role/testrole',
        JobName='nameOfMyJob',
        LanguageCode='en'
    )
    print(response)
    return "response"
```

It keeps generating this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartSentimentDetectionJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::randomNumbers:assumed-role/testrole/testfunc is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::randomNumbers:role/testrole because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "d3a54dbd-a011-42f0-bc74-440ce9cbaa8d",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.start_sentiment_detection_job(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I am not sure if there is an error with my code, or if it is a role/permission issue. For the role, this is what I have as my trust entity:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a code or a permission issue?
Here is the API I used for the response line: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/comprehend.html#Comprehend.Client.start_sentiment_detection_job
Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: here is my updated user json policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::randomNumbers:role/testrole"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, your user `arn:aws:sts::randomNumbers:assumed-role/testrole/testfunc` needs this policy attached.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::randomNumbers:role/testrole"
    }]
}
```

Refer to this doc for more information as to why `iam:PassRole` is needed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I created an user and added this policy to the permission JSON, but I still get the same error message. Do you think it is an error with my code within the start_sentiment_detection_job API portion?

Comment: Could you please show me the policy json for the User in question (Remove any sensitive params if needed). The error itself is explicitly permission denied so the user role running the above code needs to have the `iam:PassRole`. Are you sure the error is the same as above?

Comment: Hi thank you very much. I attached the user policy I did as an edit, and it does have pass role.